# Uniqueness of Riemann Sum to Definite Integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-sum

My child recently was asked a question in Calculus I on the conversion Riemann sums to their equivalent definite integrals.  This got me wondering whether this conversion is in general unique.

1. Given,
   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}g(i,n),$$
   and assuming the limit exists and is finite, can one uniquely decompose $g(i,n)$ into $f(x_i)$ and a $\Delta x$ in order to determine the corresponding definite integral
   $$\int_a^b f(x) dx?$$
2. If the decomposition is in general not unique (a counter example would be appreciated), can relatively simple conditions be placed on $g(i,n)$ such that the decomposition is unique?

Comment: You seem to be missing some parts of the definition.  The limits $a$ and $b$ have nothing to do with $g$.  You seem to be thinking of $g(i,n)$ as $f(a+\frac in(b-a))$ but do not say so.

Comment: Riemann sums  (strictly speaking) are finite sums.  Each $g(i,n)$ can be any $f(x)$ in the particular interval.

Comment: The way they typically pose these problems is that they don't give you $a$ or $b$, they ask you to figure it out from the form of $g(i,n)$.

Comment: And @herbsteinberg, Go Bulldogs.  Yale 2003.

Comment: The easiest nonuniqueness to implement is $\int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{a+1}^{b+1} f(x-1) \,\mathrm{d}x$, obtained by using $f(a +\frac{i}{n}(b-a)) = f((a+1) + \frac{i}{n}((b+1)-(a+1))-1)$.

Comment: I have prepared notes for describing how to arrange for $a = 0, b = 1$ regardless of the choice of $g(i,n)$.  They're too long to transcribe here.  There is no condition on $g$ that yields uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you @EricTowers, you've proven my point.  The conversion isn't unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced that such a decomposition exists, in the very general form stated in the OP. But there's an easy reason that such decompositions aren't unique: write down, for instance, the Riemann-sum definitions of
$$
\int_0^1 \sin x\,dx \quad\text{and}\quad \int_3^4 \sin (x-3)\,dx.
$$

Comment: Thanks @GregMartin, you've proven my point that the conversion isn't unique.